# Use MongoDB ObjectID to Group By Date (ymd) and unique IP per day

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Input:

```
{_id:ObjectID(123),ip:'123.123.123.123'}
{_id:ObjectID(123),ip:'123.123.123.123'}
{_id:ObjectID(124),ip:'123.123.123.124'}
{_id:ObjectID(125),ip:'123.123.123.125'}
```

Output:

```
{2019-03-20: 1}
{2019-03-21: 1}
{2019-03-22: 1}
```

I'm messing around with this all day to extract the timestamp from the mongo ID and use it to do a daily distinct count on the IP but I'm not getting it... I always end up with a per IP count, as in IP on day X was found 4 times... not unique IPs on day X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) and [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html) to get date from `ObjectId` and then use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to get unique IP addresses per day. In the last step you need [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get length of `ip` array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $dateToString: { date: { $toDate: "$_id" }, format: '%Y-%m-%d' } },
            ip: { $addToSet: "$ip" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            date: "$_id",
            ipCount: { $size: "$ip" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: that was quick :D - so one issue here compose.com uses MongoDB 3.6.8 and it says $toDate nor $convert exists :/

Comment: @Toby I'm afraid you need to upgrade to 4.0 or preprocess your documents and add ISODate field. You can do that In Mongo shell https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/

Comment: can't really upgrade since this is out of my hands with compose.com and can't really alter the data... I tried around with getTimestamp but seems to go nowhere

Comment: @Toby you need a script to add new field of type ISODate - that seems to be simplest workaround for MongoDB < 4.0

Comment: couldnt you just do getTimestamp() from the _id and work with that? if you can write it into the db you can read it out no?

Comment: "_id" : { "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
            "date": "$_id"
          }} - works fine

Comment: @Toby yes I know, the thing is that type conversion for Aggregation Framework was introduced in 4.0

Comment: alright so for 3.8 the date: $_id works fine - thanks - let me know if you go to any of the krk meetups and i get you a beer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Under MongoDB v3.8 the below works - all thanks to @mickl

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            "_id" : {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                    "date": "$_id"
                }
            },
            "ip": { $addToSet: "$ip" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            date: "$_id",
            ipCount: {
                $size: "$ip"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            date: -1
        }
    }
]);
```